# C# Regex find and replace

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I am trying to replace all occurrences of Secured="*" with Secured="testValue"

```
int testValue = 9;
string text = "Test blah Secured=\"6\" Test blah Secured=\"3\" ";

 Regex r = new Regex("Secured=\".*\"  ");
text = r.Replace(text, "Secured=\" \" + newValue.toString() + \"\" ");
```

Here is my method, the issue is it changes nothing?

```
    [Published]
    public string GetConvertedVdiXML(string myText, int newValue)
    {
        string text = myText;
        Regex r = new Regex("Secured=\".*\"  ");
        text = r.Replace(text, "Secured=\" " + newValue.ToString() + " \" ");

        return text;
    }
```

The issue is it is not updating?

Comment: What do you mean by "not updating"? Is the returned value not what you were expecting?

Comment: GetConvertedVdi**XML**  - If this is XML there are better ways than RegExp

Comment: Of course it matches nothing, your regex pattern is looking for Secured=".*" followed by 2 spaces. That pattern does not exist in your input string. Every instance of Secured="*" in your input is only followed by a single space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
    text = r.Replace(text, "Secured=\" \"" + newValue.ToString() + "\" ");
```

Since the `newValue` is a variable. It cannot be part of a string. The updated code should work:

```
int newValue = 9;
string text = "Test blah Secured=\"6\" Test blah Secured=\"3\" ";
Regex r = new Regex(@"Secured=""[^""]*"" ");
text = r.Replace(text, "Secured=\"" + newValue.ToString() + "\" ");
```

Output: `Test blah Secured="9" Test blah Secured="9"`

Also, here is the function code:

```
public string GetConvertedVdiXML(string myText, int newValue)
{
    string text = myText;
    Regex r = new Regex(@"Secured=""[^""]*"" ");
    text = r.Replace(text, "EditableBy=\"" + newValue.ToString() + "\" ");
    return text;
}
```

Comment: The returned string has nothing changed? example string could be: 
        <TEST1
 Secured="0"
                />
        <TEST2
        Secured="0"/> so the " might not have \ before them